# Avoid popup blocker when opening new window that requires an async lookup

Tags: javascript, meteor, popup, iron-router

I've got a button in my Meteor application that does the following:

user clicks button > event calls method > method calls external api using http > external api returns single sign on link > method returns link > event opens new window (tab) with link as url

My problem is that the new tab is being blocked by a popup blocker even though it is based on user action

Here's the event code:

```
Template.welcome.events({
  'click #accessLms': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
​
    var submitButton = $('#accessLms').button('loading');
​
    Meteor.call('getLmsLink', function(error, portalLink) {
      if(error) {
        sAlert.error(error.message);
        submitButton.button('reset');
      } else if(portalLink) {
        window.open(
          portalLink,
          '_blank'
        );
        submitButton.button('reset');
      }
    }); 
  }
});
```

Here is the method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'getLmsLink': function () {

      [set vars...]

      try {
          var response = HTTP.call( verb, wceaApiAddress + endPoint, {
              headers: {
                  "Request-Time": timeStamp,
                  "Api-Key": key,
                  "Signature": hash
              }
          });
      } catch(error) {
          throw new Meteor.Error(501, 'There was a problem getting a link to the E-Learning Portal');
      }
​
      var result = JSON.parse(response.content);
      var portalLink = result.records.accessLink;
      return portalLink;
  }
});
```

Comment: _“even though it is based on user action”_ – it is not _directly_ based on it (and only then it won’t be blocked) – the asynchronous request “de-couples” it from the original click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic approach:

1. On the click event in your app open a new window with a specific url to your own app
2. Include a route parameter that can be used in the new window, for example `/redirect/token/`
3. In the `Template.onCreated` event of the template used in that route, perform the method call and get the url and auth token to the 3rd party site.
4. Finally just set `location = newSiteHref` in that same code (in the new window) and redirect the user

Comment: This solution worked perfectly, thanks for the help!